# MotionEvent not firing

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener

I want to implement a drag and drop but it turned out to be ridiculously time consuming, here is the problematic code:

```
public  class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

public static float sharedX,sharedY;

public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    sharedX = motionEvent.getX();
    sharedY = motionEvent.getY();

    switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
            View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
            view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
            view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;


        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

The action down and action cancel are being fired, although action cancel not giving correct result (motionevent.getX isn't a sane, normal value)

None of the other events fire. I can't figure out why and I gave up trying.